# why @UniqueConstraint doesn't work in hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, unique-constraint

I added unique constraint annotation but still I can insert duplicate entry.

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"firstName", "LastName"})})
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String LastName;
    //getter and setter and no-arg constructor
```

```
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Student student1 = new Student("alireza", "rayani");
        Student student2 = new Student("alireza", "rayani");
        session.save(student1);
        session.save(student2);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally ,I found out the problem ,I changed dialect  from

```
properties.put(Environment.DIALECT,"org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
```

to

```
properties.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect");
```

Comment: You usually don't need to specify the dialect. Hibermate default dialect resolver will pick the best based on database metadata provided by the jdbc driver

Comment: yes , i don't know this feature of hibernate .thanks for telling.

Answer (score 0):

The schema for your database is generated by Hibernate? @UniqueConstraint is only used to generate the schema. If the database already exists, you should execute the `alter table` on it to add the constraint.

Comment: i drop the table and hibernate created the table but doesn't work

Comment: Can you post the SQL that Hibernate generates to create the table? Also, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: ```Hibernate: create table Student (id bigint not null auto_increment, LastName varchar(255), firstName varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM
Hibernate: alter table Student drop index UKb39qrjwnlotgtyka7hxrxkiyy
Hibernate: alter table Student add constraint UKb39qrjwnlotgtyka7hxrxkiyy unique (firstName, LastName)```

Comment: I tested in oracle and it was okay but in mysql doesn't work.

Comment: It appears that the Unique constraint is created (you can set a more comprehensive name for it with the `name` attribute). If the code above does the 2 inserts and after that you can do a select on the DB and get 2 rows with duplicated firstName, LastName pair it has to be some issue with your DBMS configuration